# Passing styles from parent to mui component in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi I have the following React component that positions its children with styles.

```
const styles = () => ({  
    bathButt : {
        top :278,
        left : 336
    },        
})
class AudioZones extends Component {

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return ( 
                <IconButton  className={classes.bathButt} >
                    <Speaker/> 
                </IconButton>
                );
             } 
        }
export default withStyles(styles) (AudioZones);
```

I have created a child component "AudioZone" 
     render() 
        return ( 
            
                 
             );
    }
which i substitute into the parent

```
render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return ( 
                <AudioZone/>                    );
             }
```

However I have run into trouble on how I pass down the "bathButt" style so that the position of the button is set in the parent but read and rendered by the child.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `withStyles` you can use  Higher-Order Components (HOC) to pass styles from parent to child

```
const styles = () => ({
  bathButt: {
    top: 20,
    left: 30,
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  }
});


const withMyStyles = WrappedComponent => {
  const WithStyles = ({ classes }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <WrappedComponent classes={classes} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return withStyles(styles)(WithStyles);
};
```

and use it in your child component

```
class AudioZones extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <IconButton className={classes.bathButt}>
        <h1>Speaker Component</h1>
      </IconButton>
    );
  }
}
export default withMyStyles(AudioZones);
```

but insted of `withStyles` you can use `makeStyles`,i think its easer

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  bathButt: { top: 20, left: 50, color: "red" } // a style rule
});


function App(props) {
  return <AudioZones useStyles={useStyles} />;
}
```

child component

```
function AudioZones(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton className={classes.bathButt}>
        <h1>Speaker Component</h1>
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working Codesandbox for [withStyles](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-gould-1t9y1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and [makeStyles](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-chaplygin-j761p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)